# Error in ejabberd custom module to connect with mysql - more details attached

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I am trying to connect mysql db from sample mod_hellow_world and for that i followed the below steps..

1. Added in ejabberd.yml

   ```
   sql_type: mysql
   sql_server: "localhost"
   sql_database: "ejabberd"
   sql_username: "admin"
   sql_password: "admin885" 

   modules:
        mod_hello_world:
           db_type: sql
   ```

When i start ejabberd  using ./ejabberdctl start
Following error received in error.log

```
 @ejabberd_app:start:72
 Failed to start ejabberd application:
 Invalid value of option modules->mod_hello_world:
 Unknown option: db_type.
 There are no available options
```

if i remove db_type: sql it works fine... is there any more configuration need to done to connect mysql?

Comment: Or refer  simple ejabberd custom module to connect to  mysql with yml configuration if exist..

Comment: `db_type` is in every case an unknown and therefore illegal property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module defines what modules can be configured. See  functions mod_opt_type and mod_options in many modules.

In those functions the developer describes what options the module will accept.

Remember to run "make options" after addinf those functions.

Comment: source file with my changes

Comment: That code is hard to view in comments. Can you edit your original post with that information? maybe it can be read correctly there

Comment: can you suggest me what are all changes required to this module to connect mysql  default schema is ejabberd : https://github.com/raelmax/mod_http_offline/blob/master/mod_http_offline.erl

Comment: This is in ejabberd.yml  i used


auth_method: sql

sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "admin"
sql_password: "password1"
.
.
.

modules:
  mod_http_offline:
    db_type: sql

Comment: Error :                              [critical] Failed to start ejabberd application: Invalid value of option modules->mod_http_offline: Unknown option: db_type. There are no available options

Comment: Hello Badlop any update on above my request.

Comment: mod_http_offline.erl is very old, maybe this implements the same and works correctly? https://github.com/edwardchow33/mod_offline_http_post